# URL Manipulation With Google Analytics Advanced Filters

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, I have a view for a web site in which I'm trying to use Advanced filters to codify a transformation on the "Request URI" field:

- if the Request URI matches "/product/[productid]/someproductscreen" then
  I want to strip "/[productid]" from the Request URI so I can combine all
  visits to /someproductscreen across all products
- all Request URIs that do not match the pattern above should be passed
  into the view unmodified

When I view the traffic in the Site Content..All Pages report, I don't want to see any values of "/[productid]" in the URIs in the "Page" column - I'd like all visits to a particular product page to roll up under a URI like "/product/warranty" or "/product/description".

Unfortunately I find it difficult to try figuring this out on my own because of the lag in seeing results in Google Analytics after making a change combined with my shaky grasp of how regular expressions are utilized in Advanced Filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here https://regex101.com/r/kRUJnU/1

Start playing with this tool it ll become really helpful on the future since personalized filters with regex matching and capturing groups are REALLY important in GA.

EDIT: How to go from regex101 to GA.

In the image below you can see how i deleted the last part of URLs when they are something like:

> www.mysite.com/vuelos/carrito/checkout/46787654567898765

Or something like:

> www.mysite.com/vuelos/carrito/46787654567898765

[image: GA filter]

Comment: regex101 is a superb tool and I'll be sure to test the regexes on it.  Also I'm hoping someone can tell me whether the URL manipulation I'm trying to achieve is even possible in GA advanced filters.

Comment: Yes, the regex i send to you can be placed on GA. I ll update the post with an image to show you.

Answer (score 1):

### GA Advanced Filter

Assuming your `[product id]` was 3 or more consecutive digits,  ie:  `/product/123456789/someproductscreen`  then this would work:

1. Advanced Filter
2. `Field A`: `Request URI`:   `^/product/\d{3,}(.*)`
3. `Field B`:
4. Output to:  `Request URI`:   `/product/{id}$A1`
5. Check `Field A Required` and `Override Output Field`

[image: GA Advanced Filter configuration using regex]

The above configuration will rewrite the `Request URI` from:

> /product/123456789/someproductscreen
>   /product/12345
>   /some/other/url

to:

> /product/{id}/someproductscreen
>   /product/{id}
>   /some/other/url

You mention you'd want to see `/product/warranty`. This would obscure the edit. My suggestion is to leave a placeholder with the edit. I use `{id}` but it could be any string, ie. `<product id>`

### Level Up the Regex

[Link to regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/kRUJnU/3)

Regular Expressions are used by GA Filters, in the above example we used regex to match a product ID that is all digits. We did this using the regular expression:

```
^(/.*/)(\d{3,})(.*)
```

This is true when Request URI has root folder `(/.*/)` followed by three or more digits: `(\d{3,})`  Finally, we capture the remainder of the URI using `(.*)`. We used groups so we can access the values in a later step.

GA Advanced Filters can persist groups extractions from `Field A` and `Field B`. We use this feature to rebuild a `Request URI` using the `Output To -> Constructor`. Below is an example of condensing dynamic Ids to a static string:

> $A1{id}$A3

`$A1` will extract 1st group from `Field A`. `$A3` would extract the third group from `Field A` if it were to exist. `{id}` is a static string that is a placeholder for the dynamic value.

If your product id was a mix of alphanumeric, then we'd simply need to find a pattern that matched. You didn't provide any examples of ID, so here are a few examples of common ID patterns found in URLs:

```
 [A-Z]-\d+          // matches Z-764537389
 \d{4}-\d{3}-\d{2}  // matches 1234-123-12
```

Easy mode right?  What about if you have a RFC4122 compliant UUID in the URL you need match?  No problem:

```
[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}
// matches 0df98a02-c438-4c57-8d1c-2f6041804e2c
```

Note: [GA Advanced Filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) Regex is **case insensitive** by default, this can be overridden in the filter settings.

Comment: What's going to happen to urls that are not in the form "/product/[productid]/someproductscreen"?  Will this advanced filter pass them through unmodified (that's the behavior that I want)?

Comment: Yes, @sevzas because "Field A" is required, if no match on Field A then the filter does nothing.   Since the regex on Field A includes a very specific match on /product/<id>/etc  then you won't have an issue.  

Either way, I followed up with a scenario that would work universally to remove an <id> that followed any folder path.  So... this question is answered!  Please mark it as such :-)

Comment: I used /(\/product)(\/.*?)(\/.*) to look fa match and Output string = $A1\/RODUCTID$A3 - let's see how that works out.

Comment: What do you see that worries you?

Comment: Apologies.  I fully read the comment and you are correct that the leading slash was in the way.  The good news is that I can confirm that this whole filter works and I'll be building a few more.

Comment: @sevzas, just to confirm, you're saying my answer helped you?

Comment: yes - both yours and the other answer helped. I marked them both as answers but it appears that SO only took the second one because that's how SO seems to operate.  Let see what I can do to get the recognition that this answer deserves.

Comment: StackExchange Support said I could only check one "answer" - @Marco confirmed that I was on the right track which I found extremely valuable so all I could do is to upvote your answer..